# An odd proof of the uncountability of the reals

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

So, in proving that the reals are uncountable you assume otherwise and attempt to make a list of them. Working in binary this list is of form $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ where $a_i = x_{i,1}x_{i,2},\ldots$ represents the binary expansion. Given any index $j$ some real number (actually, an infinite number of them) has its $j$th digit $1$. If $x_{j,j} \neq 1$ we can swap $a_j$ with $a_k$ such that $k > j$ and $x_{k,k} = 1$; by the remark above such an $a_k$ exists. Because $k > j$ we do not undo any previous work. Thus we can assume that $x_{j,j} = 1$ for all $j$. Then $0$ is not in our enumeration.

This is of course the diagonal argument but it is a little unsettling to me that specifying any decimal expansion in advance, we could have made the exact same argument to show that ${\it any}$ real number is not in our enumeration. Is there something wrong with this method or is uncountability just this strange?

Comment: The real you exhibit is not completely arbitrary: it can't be in the list, precisely.

Comment: To echo @arbautjc: the real you have produced is far from arbitrary, it is constructed in a very precise way so as to differ from all preceding reals in the list.

Comment: yes, the enumeration is not arbitrary - you may have to swap elements depending on the number you do not want to see

Comment: OK, I've changed that part. However while the real I have produced - $0$ - is not arbitrary, we could have made similar swaps (instead of requiring all diagonal entries tobe $1$) to show that any real is not in our (swapped) enumeration.

Comment: Could your list have been such that Cantor's diagonal method returned $0$?  Yes, I guess.  But any supposed enumeration of the real line that omits $0$ is a pretty poor enumeration of the real line!  (Though there is a Professor in Augsburg who consistently omits $\frac{1}{3}$ from all his enumerations of the reals...)

Comment: Note that in your swapping process, some $a_j$ could get swapped to later and later locations in your sequence, infinitely often, so that you never actually make the diagonal sequence different from it.  Indeed, this is precisely what will happen to $0$ if it is in your initial list.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Ah, thank you, this is what was bothering me.

Comment: Please consider that the reals have the same status of countability as the rationals (how will you count all the numbers $m/n$?), and whether the argument is worth pursuing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't prove that $\mathbb R$ is uncountable, to see why consider the following "proof" that $\mathbb N$ is uncountable.

Assume $\mathbb N$ is countable and we have a bijection $f\colon\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ (for example, the identity!).  I want to show that there is a bijection that doesn't contain $0$, a contradiction.  Well, if $f(0) = 0$ then swap $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ so that we get a bijection $f\colon \mathbb{N \to N}$ such that $f(0) \neq 0$.

By induction if $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x < n$ but $f(n) = 0$ then swap $f(n)$ and $f(n + 1)$ so that we can assume $f(n) \neq 0$.

When we make a swap we don't alter values below $n$, so "after" all these swaps we get a perfectly well defined function $f\colon\mathbb{N \to N}$ with the property that $0$ is not in the image.  Contradiction!

Except it's **not a contradiction!**  There's no reason why the resulting function $f$ should have been a bijection.  In fact the function you get from this procedure is simply $f(n) = n + 1$.  This is not a bijection, but that doesn't mean there doesn't exist some other bijection $\mathbb{N \to N}$, like the identity function that we started with!

Comment: Yes, this illustrates the main problem that I did not see in my argument (and that Andreas Blass kindly pointed out): that an element may be swapped infinitely often.

Answer (score 3):

So you are given a function $f:\ \Bbb N\to[0,1]$ which is hopefully surjective. By some involved, and by no means "finitary", process you then construct a new function $g:\ \Bbb N\to[0,1]$ that does not contain $0$ in its image. I don't see how this proves anything about the given $f$.

Answer (score 3):

Although the argument is often presented as a proof by contradiction, it really isn’t one. Rather, it shows how, given any function $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$, you can actually construct a specific real number $r_f$ that is not in the range of $f$. Thus, no function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb R$ can be surjective, and by definition $\Bbb R$ must be uncountable. When you modify your original $f$ by swapping two values, you’re simply replacing $f$ by a different function $g:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$, and the same argument shows that the range of $g$ is not all of $\Bbb R$. Since $g$ and $f$ are not the same function, it should not by surprising that $r_g\ne r_f$.